# Wordpress theme not recognized

Tags: wordpress, nginx, themes, symlink, rocketeer

In my local, it works. Here I use [rocketeer](https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer) to deploy the project.

In server, here is the `wp-content/themes` directory

```
./
../
foobar/
.gitignore
index.php -> /var/www/foobar.example.com/shared/wp-content/themes/index.php
twentyfifteen -> /var/www/foobar.example.com/shared/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/
```

In the admin panel, I only see **twentyfifteen**, but cannot see the **foobar**.

I'm using Nginx here

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foobar.example.com;
    root /var/www/foobar.example.com/current;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~/\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress to recognized your themes you need to add an special header to your css something like this:

```
/*
Theme Name: Your Theme Name
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/themes/twentythirteen
Author: Your Name
Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: 
Version: 1.0
*/
```

Check this out for more info https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the reason. I symlink all the wordpress core files

```
index.php
wp-activate.php
wp-admin
wp-blog-header.php
wp-comments-post.php
wp-config.php
wp-cron.php
wp-includes
wp-links-opml.php
wp-load.php
wp-login.php
wp-mail.php
wp-settings.php
wp-signup.php
wp-trackback.php
xmlrpc.php
```

Let's take `index.php` as example, the last line is

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

When I actually `echo` it out, the `dirname( __FILE__ )` is point to the shared folder.